# How to pass json data from url to sql?

Tags: c#

I get json data from url

and I have created the corresponding column  in the database

then  I tried to pass this data to SQL

here's my code

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Inserch>> GetMaskmapdata()
{
    string targetURI = "https://quality.data.gov.tw/dq_download_json.php?nid=116285&md5_url=53a72b2dcfdd9ecae43afda4b86089be";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(targetURI);
    var pharmacy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Inserch>>(response);

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    connection.Open();
    string listvalue = string.Join(",", pharmacy);
    string sql = "Insert into pharmacy(ID,Name,Address,Phonenumber) values(@ID,@Name,@Address,@Phonenumber)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    foreach (var item in pharmacy)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", item.ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", item.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", item.Address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber", item.Phonenumber);
                
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
    
    return pharmacy;
}
```

It can't be work
What did i do wrong?

Comment: You keep adding *new* parameters. add them once (before the loop) and (in the loop) *update* their values

Comment: Also, do not close the connection inside the loop: a second iteration will see a closed connection and fail. Close it after the loop, or (better) use a `using` block

Comment: "It can't be work" doesn't really describe the problem. Please tell us what error you're getting or how the code works different from your expectation.

Comment: Your **targetURI** is not a rest service. It's a downloadable file. Check it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your data storage part, you keep adding new parameters. Also you close the connection after the first iteration, blocking it for a second one.

A better solution for that part (ignoring getting the data from that URL):

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connstr))
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql = "Insert into pharmacy(ID,Name,Address,Phonenumber) values(@ID,@Name,@Address,@Phonenumber)";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    
    // add parameters once (guessing at types and sizes - please correct)
    var pId = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    var pName = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    var pAddress = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    var pPhoneNumber = cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    
    foreach (var item in pharmacy)
    {
        // update the values of the parameters
        pId.Value = item.ID;
        pName.Value = item.Name;
        pAddress.Value = item.Address;
        pPhoneNumber.Value = item.PhoneNumber;

        // execute the command with the latest parameter values
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // do NOT close the connection, you may still need it for a second iteration
    }
}
// connection is closed automatically by exiting the 'using' block
```

and now you can still `return pharmacy;`.